# Почему оператор += не накапливается ? (на примере функции ввывод обратного числа)

Tags: javascript, for

Есть функция которая выводи числа в обратном порядке.

```js
function reverse(number) {
   number += "";
   let reversnumber = "";
   for (let i = number.length-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
      reversnumber += number[i];
      console.log(reversnumber);
   }
   return {"Обратное число": +reversnumber}
}
console.log(reverse(12345))
```

Вопрос почему выводит 54321, а не сумму (5+4+3+2+1) 15?  Вот эта строчка **reversnumber += number[i];** говорит о накапливание переменной. С другой стороны если в коде я поменяю данную строку на reversnumber -= number[i]; мне выводит -15.  Почему в первом случае выводит при += 54321, а при -= -15

Comment: Потому что reversnumber это строка и данные объединяются, а не суммируются

Comment: Ты превратил число в строчку `number += ""`... Далее работаешь со строкой... А строки конкатенируются, не суммируются. Преврати строку/символ в число - будет сложение.

Comment: Спасибо, дошло.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что оператор `+` или объединяет строки (конкатенирует) или складывает числа, а оператор `-` только вычитает числа друг из друга и не взаимодействует со строками.

Но JS отличный язык и полагает что вы это знаете и учитываете, поэтому он скастовывает ваши буквы в цифры и отлично складывает их, чтобы у вас получилось -15

Починить ваш код можно с помощью несложной магии
`reversnumber += number[i];`
заменить на
`reversnumber += parseInt(number[i]);`

Comment: Тогда уж детализируйте ответ и поясните, почему при **-** идет работа с цифрами, а с **+** со строками ) И как это исправить

Comment: ладно тогда можете обьяснить почему при reversnumber += number[i]; выводит 54321, а если += number[i] * 1; выводит 15. Что изменилось?

Comment: @Дмитрий, умножение "неявно" преобразовало строку в число. Такое преобразование может сделять и `унарный +` - `+"1234"`.

Comment: В первом случае вы складываете строчки и ```+``` конкатенирует, а во втором вы их кастуете в числа и ```+``` их складывает

Comment: Всем спасибо, разобрался.